# Android Wear PendingResult onResult callback not being called

Tags: android, wear-os

after a sendMessage, i get a PendingResult and set an onResult callback. this callback never happens.

```
PendingResult<MessageApi.SendMessageResult> messageResult = Wearable.MessageApi
            .sendMessage(googleApiClient, senderNodeId, NOTE_REPLY_PATH,
                         replyMessage.getBytes());

    if (messageResult.isCanceled())
        Log.d(TAG, "result cancelled!");

    messageResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult)
        {
            replyStatus = sendMessageResult.getStatus();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "confirm result");
                    confirm(replyStatus.getStatusCode() == WearableStatusCodes.SUCCESS);
                }
            });
        }
```

isCancelled is not the case. I tried awat() but this cannot be called on the UI thread (which this is). It perturbs be that you have to set the callback *after* calling sendMessage (what if it's already sent by that point). but this is the way the docs want it.

basically my "confirm result" never happens.

any ideas why? thanks

EDIT:

turns out sometimes im not connected to any nodes. which is probably why. so how is this interface meant to convey that if it can't call the callback. this sendmessage interface design is poor. instead it should be something like

status = sendMessage(callback, other args);

because there's no way for it to tell you that the callback can't happen.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be connected to get the callback. Due to the asynchronous nature of these calls, you should always register callbacks that would inform you if the connectivity state has changed (and even more, to be informed if your target node gets disconnected, etc).

The pattern of setting the callback *after* the call itself is not an issue; framework makes sure that if your call makes it to the wearable code, the PendingResult callback that you registered afterward is called.

Just to be very clear here, even if you received a callback with a successful status, it doesn't mean that your message (using MessageApi) has been successfully *delivered* to the target node; a "success" only means your message has been queued (which only happens if your device is connected to the target node) and still it may never be delivered successfully, due to the network conditions (say, your message is queued and you get a success result but before delivery, connection is disrupted). On the contrast, DataApi guarantees eventual sync even if there is no connectivity to other nodes at the time that an item is added using DataApi; when connectivity is re-established, sync happens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're saying i should monitor the Node api and know not to try sending if i've been disconnected. that would fix it. However, it's still rather annoying that sendMessage can't return an error code in such cases instead of just doing nothing.

I do get dropped messages, so i had to implement a message reply ACK/NAK to _really_ find out if the message had been delivered. You're suggesting i should use the dataapi perhaps? Does that have overhead. I don't really have data to synchronise only a message to send that i need to be sure it has been received, whence the ACK.

Comment: No, I am not suggesting to use DataApi if it doesn't fit your use case; I had mentioned it to emphasize that the contract for MessageApi is based on a best-effort attempt while DataApi has a strong contract for delivery. You need to know if you are connected before using any of the APIs that use the ApiClient as an argument and program in a way that connectivity to other nodes can go away at any moment; if it is important to send and receive messages, use the ACK confirmation as you are already doing.